# How can I move videos back into the Camera Roll?

Tags: ios, windows, photos, video

Every so often I move all the pictures and videos off my phone onto my desktop in order to free space on the phone. I have this app called 1 Second Every Day which uses video clips from my Camera Roll to build longer videos.

I moved all my pictures and videos off of my roll before realizing I'd need them to make this month's video. Is there a way I can restore videos taken with the phone back onto the Camera Roll?

I'm running Windows 10 with iTunes 12.3.12.25.

Comment: You can sync them back, but they won't be on the camera roll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you can bring them back into your Camera Roll, or at least in a place where you can use them in 1SE, just by copying them into Dropbox.

1. Copy your MOV files into Dropbox.
2. Install the Dropbox app on your device.
3. For each video, select the ellipsis icon and then Export, then Save Video.